# Samsung S4 ADB devices list of devices attached is empty on win7

Tags: android, usb, adb

Using Samsung S4, attached to the win7. adb devices shows that the list of devices attached is empty.

1. Checked android developers:
   http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html, followed the steps
   to install drivers from
   D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver ,
   not working
2. Checked other posts,

`adb kill-server

adb start-server 
adb devices`,

not working

3. Restarted both phone and computer, not working.
4. disconnect/connect phones repeatedly, not working.

Comment: after point 1. you should be able to see the device (depends on your reading skills) *followed the steps to install drivers* <= you didn't followed ...just check http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers ... you have link to samsung download page *If you are developing on Windows and would like to connect an Android-powered device to test your applications, then you need to install the appropriate USB driver. This document provides links to the web sites for several original equipment manufacturers (OEMs), where you can download the appropriate USB driver for your device.*

Comment: oh, i thought samsung s4 was a google play phone, not a OEM.

Answer (score -1):

Turned out that WIN7 is too smart (or too dumb). Although you chose to install drivers from the specified location, WIN7 actually decides for you that the drivers it already has (in system 32) is the latest and best drivers for you device. And this fucked up drivers identify samsung phone as some MPT device. What the fish.

Solution is to install samsung drivers from http://www.samsung.com/levant/support/model/GT-I9500ZKAMID, open your device manager (select properties on computer), only when you see " SAMSUNG Android Phone - SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface" in the device list, then it means the correct drivers are installed for samsung phone. then adb devices, you can find the device:

list of device attached:

4df1dxxxxxxx         device

Comment: Of course you have to install your device's driver. The driver you mentioned in the question is the ADB driver, not your phone's driver. If you don't want to involve in this driver mess, use Mac / Linux.

Comment: but usually if you dont install device drivers, you can still access its contents, because its a Plug-and-play device. but in adb's world, you need to install the device drivers so that it can be identified by adb as a android-driven device.

Comment: no. that's not true for Windows. Multiple drivers are usually required for 1 mobile phone, including Mass Storage Device, modem, bluetooth, and the mobile phone itself, etc. Some common drivers may exist in Windows 7 like Mass Storage Device (that's why you can access its file contents, but cannot start debug session of the phone), while some of them like mobile phone itself needs to be installed by users.

Comment: i didn't install Samsung drivers but from win7 i can access phone contents because win7 has used the generic drivers for the devices. To be able to debug the phone, it is required to install samsung usb drivers. But strange thing happened just now, when i pluged in the S4, it is not recognized by win 7 again!!! now it shows under portable device - galaxy S4. not a "android phone" anymore and it does not show in the "adb devices". I uninstalled the drivers and restart and install samsung drivers again and again. nothing worked. i think im gonna throw up.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to turn on the "allow usb debug" on the phone '-_-